# Api Call in Python

Tags: python, api

I'm using Indicoio api in Python. I can't to understand how to request an output from an API. Here's of what I've done so far:

- Install Python 3.6 on Windows 7

  - Instal Pycharm Community
  - New Project + New .py File
  - Install Indicoio via Project Interpreter

When I write this code using my API key in Pycharm or Idle nothing happens and I get "Process finished with exit code 0" Or syntax error

```
import indicoio
indicoio.config.api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# single example
indicoio.sentiment("I love writing code!")

# batch example
indicoio.sentiment([
    "I love writing code!",
    "Alexander and the Terrible, Horrible, No Good, Very Bad Day"
])
```

Here's the documentation : https://indico.io/docs

Comment: Your code does not output anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running fine, but you're not actually telling it to print anything.

Try wrapping your calls in a print statement like this:

```
import indicoio
indicoio.config.api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# single example
print(indicoio.sentiment("I love writing code!"))

# batch example
print(indicoio.sentiment([
    "I love writing code!",
    "Alexander and the Terrible, Horrible, No Good, Very Bad Day"
]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! They need to make more obvious examples.